# Protect you application from changes from a third party application

Tags: architecture

I was made this question on an interview today: You want to make an application that relies on a third-party application but you want to shield it so that changes from the third-party application don't break your application.

What I say was that I would create a proxy application so that I can develop my application and if ever a new release of the third-party breaks the application, then I would change the proxy.

Is that a real solution? Is there any other approaches?

Thanks.

Comment: @user487117:Are you referring to third-party application or third-party library?If it is an application is it deployed also by you or by third party and you exchange data with it?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you can't be absolutely certain that future changes don't break your software. This is why .NET has the attribute `Obsolete`: to provide backward compatibility while giving you a version or two to change your code to keep up.

The only real fix I can imagine is actually packaging the third-party app with your software. This way, the version **won't** change until you're ready for a new release.

Comment: He is asking about third party application, not third party library though

Comment: @384706, true enough. However, I'm giving the **only** way to ensure application stability that I can think of. If you can't control the version of the software that you rely on, you are at the mercy of the 3rd-party app and had better have quick updates and releases.